# How do you prove that this TM decides a language that is undecidable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability

In Sipser's Introduction to the Theory of Computation, there is an exercise that asks to prove $T$ decides $A_{TM}$, which is the language

$$A_{TM} = \{ \langle M,w \rangle | M \text{ is a TM and $w \in L(M)$}\}.$$

$T$ is a TM defined as follows. On input $\langle M,w \rangle$,

1. Write the description of a TM $R$ that works as follows. On input $x$,

   - Run $T_A$ on $x$.
   - If $T_A$ accepts $x$ then accept.
   - If $T_A$ rejects $x$ then run $M$ on input $w$ and accept if $M$ does.
2. Run $P$ on input $\langle R \rangle$, accept if $P$ rejects and reject if $P$ accepts.

Here:

- $T_A$ is a TM that decides the language $A$.
- $P$ is a TM that can decide the language
  $$  Z = \{\langle M\rangle | M\text{ is a TM and } L(M) = A\}. $$
- $ A = \{(0 \cup 1)^a(1 \cup 2)^b(2 \cup 3)^c | a \geq b\} $.

How can you prove that $T$ decides $A_{TM}$ ?

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The exact definition of $A$ is not important; you just need $A \neq \Sigma^*$. When is $L(R) \neq A$? (look at the third line!)

Comment: when M does not accept w? how does that prove T decides $A_{TM}$ ?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to work that out. You just have to "chase" the definitions.

Comment: in the case when $L(R) \neq A$.. when M accepts w, does that mean R accepts A_TM ?

Comment: If $M$ accepts $w$ then $R$ accepts *all* inputs (why?). I suggest you work on your own from now. Don't give up. Just follows the definitions through. The point of this exercise is for you to understand the definitions – there is no thinking required beyond that.